# Counting the occurence of cells colored yellow; upon reading the color purple, code outputs count and loops

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function that will loop through data that looks like the following:

[The purple represents the ycolor in the code; when the code reads this color I want the count to be displayed and then reset to zero. This is because the purple represents a new data set (note: there are 7,541 purple lines in the spreadsheet, hence why I want to use a looping VBA function rather than counting). The yellow represents the xcolor in the code; when the code reads this color I want the count to begin and add +1 for every yellow cell found between purple cells. With the code running correctly I would want it to display a 6 for the first purple row, and a 2 for the second purple row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwUzy.png)

In all, there are 185,000 rows in the spreadsheet, so the display doesn't need to be located in a specific location, it could just be an array of numbers that I could graph into a histogram to show the range of frequencies.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range, log_page As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Dim ycolor As Long

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
ycolor = log_page.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        ElseIf datax.Interior.ColorIndex = ycolor Then
            Debug.Print CountCcolor
            CountCcolor = 0
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

In the code the range_data is the comments column, the criteria is chosen by selecting an empty cell containing just the color yellow, and the log_page is also chosen by selecting an empty cell containing just the color purple (the log_page represents where I want the code to print the total, clear the count, then loop).

I have been able to write a function that correctly tallies all of the yellow rows in the entire spreadsheet; however, have been unable to get it to loop and display outputs correctly in accordance with the purple rows.

Comment: It would help if you answered BruceWayne's question on your other post (which seems to be the same question as this post?)  Posting a new question if you don't get instant answers on your original post is not a good tactic here - it's better to instead engage with people who took the time to post comments there than just move on to another post.  It's not like people won't notice...

Comment: A function called as a UDF from a worksheet can only return a value (or a list of values if used as an array formula) so you'll need to either call this differently (ie. from a VBA Sub) or you'll have to enter it as an array formula (over a range large enough to handle to full output)

Comment: @TimWilliams my apologies, thank you for the comment. This is my first time ever using this site. I just now realized I can tag people in my comments to give them a notification that I responded; also, I updated my code to attempt to add a loop so I wanted to create a new post with that update (although I now realize I should just edit my original, which I have done). As far as the sub/array suggestions.. thank you I will go back and attempt both to see which works best.

Comment: One question which would be useful for you to address: how is the original color being applied?  Is it conditional formatting?  The answer to that makes a difference.

Comment: @TimWilliams The way the color was originally applied was by using a filter for key words; I used replace to replace the key words with their original wording but with a highlight (either purple or yellow) as well. So as far as I know this is not conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a sub called from another procedure:

```
Sub Tester()

    With ActiveSheet
        CountCcolor .Range("A1:A30"), .Range("A3"), .Range("A1"), .Range("C1")
    End With

End Sub



Sub CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range, _
                log_page As Range, rngOutput As Range)

    Dim arrCounts(), resNum As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Dim ycolor As Long

    'size output array for worst-case scenario (all purple rows)
    ReDim arrCounts(1 To range_data.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
    ycolor = log_page.Interior.ColorIndex
    resNum = 0

    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = ycolor Then

            resNum = resNum + 1
            arrCounts(resNum, 1) = datax.Row '<< log the header row
            arrCounts(resNum, 2) = 0

        ElseIf datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
            If resNum > 0 Then
                 'increment the count
                 arrCounts(resNum, 2) = arrCounts(resNum, 2) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next datax

    'populate the counts to the worksheet
    rngOutput.Resize(resNum, 2).Value = arrCounts

End Sub
```

Input and output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, patience, and help better understanding the use of this website. As I am very new to VBA (just beginning and self-taught) how to you operate using a sub as compared to a function? With the function I was able to just type "=ColorCcount(inputs)" and I would get the outputs; when trying to do this with the sub I get an error stating "The name that you entered is not valid", how should I execute the sub? Thank you again.

Comment: You can't call a sub like it's a function.  Copy the code into a regular module, make the necessary adjustments to the ranges in the `Tester` sub, then run it  (with the cursor inside the Tester sub, hit F5)